# Is my question about Netbeans more suitable for Stack Overflow or SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1324812/cannot-run-assembly-code-on-netbeans-8-1-on-windows-10) yesterday and one of the users pointed out to me that this question may be better for Stack Overflow. I feel that my question involves configuring Netbeans to run assembly code so it is on-topic here.

Additionally, please point out any flaws in my question. I don't understand why it has been down-voted twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there might not strictly be any programming happening in the question, it is definitely about a software tool used primarily by programmers. Stack Overflow's [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) includes this guidance, emphasis mine:

> ...if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm,
> - or **software tools commonly used by programmers; and is**
> - **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**
>
> … then you’re in the
>   right place to ask your question!

Therefore, I believe it should make a good Stack Overflow question.

I suspect the downvotes are from people who deemed the question off-topic for Super User. From a quick scan, it looks well written to me. You might consider putting the build output in monospace/code formatting for better readability, though.

Comment: The first revision of the question only had images, of errors, which were extremely hard to read.  *The original errors were also caused by the user attempting to compile Linux code on Windows.*